# R and probability

Tags: r, probability-theory

I'm trying to write a code to get the probability of a certain scenario. There are 52 cards broken down into 4 Suit piles. 1 card is randomly drawn from each pile to make a 4 card combination and then the cards are put back into their piles. How do you work out the probability of the combination having only 1 King?
I have tried the following but I think I am doing something wrong

```
cards <- c(2:10,'J','Q', 'K','A') 
v <- sample(rep(cards,1:13),1000,replace=T)
cat('The probability of getting a King is approximately:',sum(v=='K')/length(v),'\n')
```

Comment: First, your `rep` is wrong, see `rep(1:4, 1:4)` to see how; instead try `rep(cars,4)`. Second, you are testing for single cards, not groups of four. Third, you are sampling *with* replacement, which means it is possible to get four ace-of-spaces.

Comment: Try `table(replicate(1000, any(sample(rep(cards, 4), size=4) == 'K')))`.

Comment: Should I be testing with replacement if the cards are being replaced after each combination of 4 cards being drawn?

Comment: The `replace` argument is not needed when you repeat the `cards` vector 4 times. However, you can achieve the same sampling with `sample(cards, 4, replace=TRUE)`. BTW, using `any` will overcount, because it returns `TRUE` for any number of K's. Compare any simulation result to the exact value: p(K) * p(¬K)^3 * 4; you want exactly 1 K and 3 ¬K and the K can be drawn in 4 ways—1st thru 4th card. This is 1/13 * (12/13)^3 * 4.

Comment: `sample(cards,4,replace=TRUE)` is *wrong* per the definition of the trial. If you have 52 cars and pick four, then using `replace=TRUE` is pick a card and put it back, pick a card and put it back, pick a card and put it back, pick a card and put it back. If you need to prove this to yourself, try `sample(card, 100, replace=FALSE)` and wonder why it complains about `sample larger than population`.

Comment: Good point on the `any`, @EdwardCarney, you're right, I was hasty ... it should be `table(colSums(replicate(1000, sample(rep(cards,4),size=4)) == "K") > 1)`.

Comment: But you don't have 52 cards, @r2evans. You have 13 cards from which one card is chosen and replaced in the set. Done 4 times, this is isomorphic to choosing 4 cards from a deck of 52.

Comment: @EdwardCarney, what does `length(rep(cards,4))` give *you*? What about `table(rep(cards,4))`? Doesn't the first give you `52` and the second 13 counts of `4`? If so, then please explain to me again the problem, I'm missing something. (If not then, well, I'm still missing something.)

Comment: Long story short, I don't see what in my code suggests *"one card is chosen and replaced"* (`sample(...,size=4)`). I agree that I don't specifically deal with *suits*: we have four instances of the `"1"` card, four instances of the `"K"` card, etc. But disregarding the suitless nature of this deck (unimportant for this experiment), I don't see how this is counter to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your question, you can work it out using this code. This works for a single given draw of 1 card from each pile, or subsequent given draws after replacement. Doesn't work if you're interested in probability over multiple draws, or subsequent draws without replacement. It's not a repeated sampling based way to calculate.

All possible draw combos i.e. King or not king from each pile:

```
Hearts <- rep(c((rep("k",1)),(rep("n",1))),8)
Spades <- rep(c((rep("k",2)),(rep("n",2))),4)
Clubs <- rep(c((rep("k",4)),(rep("n",4))),2)
Diamonds <- rep(c((rep("k",8)),(rep("n",8))),1)

pile.possibilities <- data.frame(Hearts,Spades,Clubs,Diamonds)
```

And draw probabilities per pile:

```
pile.possibilities$H.prob <- ifelse (pile.possibilities$Hearts == "k", (1/13), (12/13))
pile.possibilities$S.prob <- ifelse (pile.possibilities$Spades == "k", (1/13), (12/13))
pile.possibilities$C.prob <- ifelse (pile.possibilities$Clubs == "k", (1/13), (12/13))
pile.possibilities$D.prob <- ifelse (pile.possibilities$Diamonds == "k", (1/13), (12/13))
```

Combined probability per combo:

```
pile.possibilities$Combo.prob <- pile.possibilities$H.prob *  
                                 pile.possibilities$S.prob *   
                                 pile.possibilities$C.prob *   
                                 pile.possibilities$D.prob
```

A certainty that you will have one of these combos.

```
> sum(Pile.combo.prob)
[1] 1
```

Filter your combinations of interest:

```
pile.possibilities$one.king.combo <- paste(pile.possibilities$Hearts,pile.possibilities$Spades,pile.possibilities$Clubs,pile.possibilities$Diamonds,sep = "")
pile.possibilities$one.king.combo <- sapply(strsplit(pile.possibilities$one.king, NULL), function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = ''))

one.king.probability<- sum(subset(pile.possibilities, one.king.combo == "knnn")$Combo.prob)
one.king.probability
[1] 0.2420083

#Final data frame used
> pile.possibilities
   Hearts Spades Clubs Diamonds     H.prob     S.prob     C.prob     D.prob Combo.prob one.king.combo
1       k      k     k        k 0.07692308 0.07692308 0.07692308 0.07692308 3.501278e-05           kkkk
2       n      k     k        k 0.92307692 0.07692308 0.07692308 0.07692308 4.201534e-04           kkkn
3       k      n     k        k 0.07692308 0.92307692 0.07692308 0.07692308 4.201534e-04           kkkn
4       n      n     k        k 0.92307692 0.92307692 0.07692308 0.07692308 5.041840e-03           kknn
5       k      k     n        k 0.07692308 0.07692308 0.92307692 0.07692308 4.201534e-04           kkkn
6       n      k     n        k 0.92307692 0.07692308 0.92307692 0.07692308 5.041840e-03           kknn
7       k      n     n        k 0.07692308 0.92307692 0.92307692 0.07692308 5.041840e-03           kknn
8       n      n     n        k 0.92307692 0.92307692 0.92307692 0.07692308 6.050208e-02           knnn
9       k      k     k        n 0.07692308 0.07692308 0.07692308 0.92307692 4.201534e-04           kkkn
10      n      k     k        n 0.92307692 0.07692308 0.07692308 0.92307692 5.041840e-03           kknn
11      k      n     k        n 0.07692308 0.92307692 0.07692308 0.92307692 5.041840e-03           kknn
12      n      n     k        n 0.92307692 0.92307692 0.07692308 0.92307692 6.050208e-02           knnn
13      k      k     n        n 0.07692308 0.07692308 0.92307692 0.92307692 5.041840e-03           kknn
14      n      k     n        n 0.92307692 0.07692308 0.92307692 0.92307692 6.050208e-02           knnn
15      k      n     n        n 0.07692308 0.92307692 0.92307692 0.92307692 6.050208e-02           knnn
16      n      n     n        n 0.92307692 0.92307692 0.92307692 0.92307692 7.260250e-01           nnnn
```